# android maven mojoexception

Tags: android, maven

```
I'm new to Android maven integration in to sonar dashboard. My aim is thru Android JUnit to get the code coverage using Emma and integrate that into sonar dashboard.
```

I'm facing difficulties in doing that and i'm getting the following exception. When run the development project with the below command

mvn clean install -Pemma

```
Please find the maven details below,



Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 14:14:56+0530)
Maven home: G:\Projects\apache-maven-3.0.4-bin\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows vista", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>andersen.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hello-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>andersen.project</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<name>MyProject- Application</name>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>

        <systemPath>E:\android_sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-14\libs\maps.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <systemPath>E:\android_sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar</systemPath>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>deps</groupId>
        <artifactId>dep1</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/acra-4.2.3.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>deps</groupId>
        <artifactId>dep2</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.1.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>deps</groupId>
        <artifactId>dep3</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/GSAndroidSDK.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>deps</groupId>
        <artifactId>dep4</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/GSAndroidSDK_src.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>deps</groupId>
        <artifactId>dep5</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/MMBrandedSDK.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>deps</groupId>
        <artifactId>dep6</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/bin/classes.dex</systemPath>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
              <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
</dependencies> 



<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>emma</id>
        <build>

            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>                      <!-- emma start -->
                        <emma>
                            <enable>true</enable>
                            <classFolders>${project.basedir}/target/classes/</classFolders>
                            <outputMetaFile>${project.basedir}/target/emma/coverage.em</outputMetaFile>
                        </emma>                        <!-- emma stop -->
                        <dex>
                            <noLocals>true</noLocals> <!-- must be set for emma -->
                        </dex>

                    </configuration>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<properties>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.emma.reportPath>target/emma/</sonar.emma.reportPath>
    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>../regalandroid-test/target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>emma</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
</properties>
```

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Hello - Parent
    [INFO] sourcecode - Application
    [INFO] SourceCode - Integration tests
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Hello - Parent 1.0
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ Hello-parent ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ Hello-parent ---
    [INFO] Installing G:\Projects\pom.xml to C:\Users\myuser\.m2\repository\andersen\project\Hello-parent\1.0\Hello-parent-1.0.pom
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building SourceCode - Application 1.0
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] The POM for com.google.android:android:jar:4.0 is missing, no dependency information available
    [WARNING] The POM for android:android:jar:4.0 is missing, no dependency information available
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Skipping Hello - Parent
    [INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Hello - Parent .................................... SUCCESS [1.157s]
    [INFO] SourceCode - Application ....................... FAILURE [0.348s]
    [INFO] SourceCode - Integration tests ................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 3.703s
    [INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 06 13:32:20 IST 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 4M/8M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SourceCode: Could not resolve dependencies for project andersen.project:SourceCode:jar:1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.android:android:jar:4.0, android:android:jar:4.0: Failure to find com.google.android:android:jar:4.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :SourceCode


It would be great, if anyone give me step by step how to use.

Thanks in Advance
```